# Why when adding items to a combobox the values are the same and not increasing by the loop?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
ComboboxItem boxitem = new ComboboxItem();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {

                boxitem.Text = i.ToString();
                comboBox1.Items.Add(boxitem);
            }
        }
```

And the class ComboboxItem :

```
public class ComboboxItem
        {
            public string Text { get; set; }
            public object Value { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return Text;
            }
        }
```

But for some reason all the items in the comboBox1 are 99
There are 100 items all of them the same 99
Instead 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 .... 99

Comment: Because you are not increasing anything.

Comment: Because `boxitem` is the *same* single `ComboboxItem` throughout your loop. Using `boxitem = new ComboboxItem()` inside the loop would fix this.

Comment: you should research the difference between value and reference types. Your class is a reference type. So when you add the entire instance to the items collection you pass only the reference to the place in the memory where the values are written. So each item points to the same location in memory. At the end of your loop the last value of `Text` is `"99"` so this is why you see the same number in each item. because there is only a single string saved in one memory location

Comment: I found a nice article worth reading: have a look at the part [Common C# Programming Mistake #1: Using a reference like a value or vice versa](https://www.toptal.com/c-sharp/top-10-mistakes-that-c-sharp-programmers-make)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you are setting the text of the same `ComboBox` item over and over and adding it to your list:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; 
{
    boxitem.Text = i.ToString();
    comboBox1.Items.Add(boxitem);
}
```

Instead, create a new `ComboBox` inside the loop and add that to the list. Just move the

```
ComboboxItem boxitem = new ComboboxItem();
```

inside your for-loop, and you're good.

Answer (score 1):

it is that you are changing the text of a single item, instead of instantiating a new one with each iteration.  This should fix it:

```
ComboboxItem boxitem = new ComboboxItem();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            //added bit follows here
            boxitem = new ComboboxItem();
            boxitem.Text = i.ToString();
            comboBox1.Items.Add(boxitem);
        }
    }
```